# NodeJS : update query does not work in MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

Consider the code below :

```
const queryString = "SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0; " +
"UPDATE fire_alarm.sensors " +
"SET smoke_level = " + smokeLevel + ", " +
    "carbondioxide_level = " + carbondioxideLevel + ", " +
    "sensor_status = '" + sensorStatus + "', " +
    "alert_status = '" + alertStatus + "'  " +
"WHERE floor_no = " + floorNumber + " AND room_no = " + roomNumber + ";  " +
"SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;";

connection.query( queryString, function (err, rows) {
    if(err){
        console.error("Error : " + err);
        res.send(err);
        return;
    }
    res.json(rows);
});
```

When executing the request, the error that I get is :

```
{
 "code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
 "errno": 1064,
 "sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE fire_alarm.sensors SET smoke_level = 6, carbondioxide_level = 6, sensor_s' at line 1",
}
```

But when I run the exact above query in the MySQL Workbench, it updates properly without any SQL error. What is the problem here and what is the possible solution for this ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution for this myself .... :)

The problem was `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES;`, Even though in MySQL it prompts an error for updating a record without key column, when executing through nodejs, you don't seem to need it.

Answer (score 0):

Not all of your variables which you added to the sql query has a single quote before and after it. So you should update like

```js
const queryString = `
    SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
    UPDATE fire_alarm.sensors
    SET smoke_level='${smokeLevel}',
        carbondioxide_level='${carbondioxideLevel}',
        sensor_status='${sensorStatus},'
        alert_status='${alertStatus}'
    WHERE floor_no='${floorNumber}' AND room_no='${roomNumber}';
    SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
`;
```